# Why promise's executor function arg named resolve()?

Tags: javascript, promise

In nearly all the documentation I read, promises are constructed with an executor function whose first argument is a function named "resolve":

```js
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});
```

But to me this is extremely confusing, because promise terminology differentiates "resolved" from "fulfilled," and this distinction is not consistently observed in the executor function naming.

According to https://github.com/domenic/promises-unwrapping/blob/master/docs/states-and-fates.md and https://promisesaplus.com/, "resolved" means that the promise has entered into some final state (fulfilled, rejected, or resolved to another promise), and "fulfilled" means the promise has been resolved successfully.

However, the executor's resolve() function is used to force the promise into a "fulfilled" state.

So my question is: why isn't the executor's resolve() function named fulfill()? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: You are free to name it anything you want.  It's your own parameter declaration.  If `fulfill` sounds better to you, then go right ahead and use that.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. Is there a reason I'm missing that explains why all the references seem to name it resolve, if fulfilled would clearly be a more accurate and consistent name?

Comment: That states and fates article is not purely consistent with your interpretation.  It says this: "it can be resolved to a non-promise value, in which case it is fulfilled with that value."  Here's it's using `resolve` as a verb which is just like the `resolve()` call.  I've always thought the fulfill and resolve terminology is a mess.  Most people speak of resolving or rejecting the promise.  Whatever objective the original designers had with "fulfill", that objective seems to have failed as the masses use `resolve` and `reject` as the two verbs for changing the state of the promise.

Comment: Gotcha, the recursive nature of promise resolution explains why resolve() is not synonymous with fulfill(), and why resolve() is indeed the better function name to use. Thank you!!

Comment: That document speaks of "resolving to a value" or "resolving to a thenable".  I guess it's only `fulfilled` if it is resolved to a value and the resolve callback can do either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one possible explanation.

A promise ultimately ends up fulfilled or rejected and it can be send directly to one of those states by fulfilling with a value or rejecting with a reason.

But, a promise can also be tied to another thenable and it will then track that thenable.  If that thenable ends up fulfilled, this promise will be fulfilled.  If that other thenable ends up rejected, this promise will be rejected.

So, with the executor, you can actually do three things:

1. Fulfill to a value (that is not a thenable).
2. Reject to a reason
3. Resolve to a thenable which will be tracked and whose ultimate disposition will be inherited by this promise.

Ahhh, but you don't need three functions to implement all this.  You can do it with just two.  #1 and #3 can use the same function and just vary what they pass to it (either a thenable or a non-thenable value).  So, you need a verb that captures both #1 and #3.  Folks have generally picked `resolve` as that verb.  It is resolved to either a value or thenable.

So, you get `new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {...});`.  You have to pick some word for the first function.  Most people writing documentation picked `resolve()`.  If you resolve to a non-thenable value, you get a fulfilled promise.  If you resolve to a thenable, this promise will track that thenable and take on it's eventual state.

Comment: @oregontrail256 - Did this answer your question?